# ASP.NET populate lists referencing each other on selected index change

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, postback, autopostback

I have an ASP.NET control with three listboxes: `LBParent`, `LBChild1` and `LBChild2`.

`LBParent` has to be filled programmatically. I do this in `Page_Load`.

When the user selects a value in `LBParent`, I want to fill both `LBChild1` and `LBChild2` with some data, programmatically. The children lists must also keep track of their selected value.

Basically, the parent list is a list of users, the first list is a list of permissions the user has, the second list is a list of permissions the user doesn't have.

My plan is to add two buttons to move permissions between the two lists.

Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work properly.

- If I populate the parent list in `Page_Load`, the selected index seems to reset. I used `ViewState` to save the index... but this seems to require an additional refresh, because it doesn't update after the PostBack. This is not acceptable.
- If I populate the children listboxes on the `OnParentSIC` event, there is no way I can keep track of their selected index. The `OnChildXSIC` events never fire, because the listboxes get repopulated "too soon". (?)

**How can I get this to work as intended?** Maybe there is a better solution but I'd really like to understand how to get this solution to work, as I can't see a possible solution at the moment.

---

Control.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="True" CodeBehind="..." Inherits="..." %>
<form runat="server">
     <asp:ListBox ID="LBParent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
                  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnParentSIC" />                               
     <asp:ListBox ID="LBChild1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
                  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnChild1SIC" />                               
     <asp:ListBox ID="LBChild2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
                  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnChild2SIC" />
</form>
```

---

Control.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populate parent
    for(...) LBParent.Items.Add(...);
}
```

Comment: `I used ViewState to save the index... but this seems to require an additional refresh` how ?? can u post code for this

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: Basically, on the SelectedIndexChanged events like `OnParentSIC` I simply called `ViewState["parentIdx"] = LBParent.SelectedIndex;`. While this event gets fired, it happens after the lists are populated, so it requires an additional page refresh. If I put the list population code in `Page_LoadComplete`, the event doesn't fire at all.

Comment: please paste all code what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Onchange-event fires, but before that the OnLoad fires. 
So:

1. The user clicks on an selection
2. A postback is triggered
3. At the server the Onload fires (and rebuilds the list)
4. The OnSelectedIndexChanged fires (which lost the selection by now)

So I would try to save the current-selected-index before you rebuild the list (in the Onload).

If you restore it later on while you are in the same 'postback' you can save it in a simple variable. No need to store in a Viewstate or Session.

Answer (score 1):

use Like this

If You are on the Same Page then You can Use `ViewState`/`Hidden Fields`
to Maintain States

First Time Adding ListItem on PageLoad Use Like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   AddListItems();
}
}

Protected Void AddListItems()
{
 // Populate parent
    for(...) LBParent.Items.Add(...);
    for(...) SecondList.Items.Add(...);
    for(...) ThirdList.Items.Add(...);
}
```

Comment: If I do this all lists get cleared on PostBack. The items aren't maintained.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Please post your whole code it will be better to find issue